# CKEditor 4 + Wordpress: How do I add a "Read More" button to the button toolbar?

Tags: wordpress, ckeditor, toolbar

I use CKEditor as my WordPress editor.

I customized the CKEditor basic toolbar to be the following:

> config.toolbar_WordpressBasic = [ [ 'Maximize', 'Styles', 'Format'],
>   ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Strike', 'RemoveFormat'],
>   ['Subscript','Superscript', 'TextColor','FontSize'], ['JustifyCenter',
>   'JustifyRight', 'Blockquote'], ['NumberedList','BulletedList',
>   'Outdent','Indent'], ['Undo','Redo'], ['SpecialChar', 'Table',
>   'Source' ] ];

How can I add a button to insert the "Read More" Tag of Wordpress? I know that CKEditor 4 has already this functionality because if I switch the "WordPress Full Toolbar" it already has such a button.